# Automate network disconnection on VM while maintaining remote connection from TFS job

Tags: tfs, network-programming

I have the following setup:

- Microsoft TFS with jobs and pipelines
- A VM under Virtual Machine Manager (VMM) which has Windows10
- The job from TFS can connect to VM to run commands remotely

My goal is to automate test case when there is no network connection inside the VM (mainly no internet connection) to verify that some features of my software under test behave as expected and do not use network to achieve my test calls.

Currently I use powershell on target machine to run scripts remotely in the VM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops .
I made research online already but I didn't find something specific to TFS and VMM.
Perhaps it is worth it to mention that I found this script online:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip link set ens32 down
sleep 20
ip link set ens32 up
```

But the script was written in a Linux and SSH connection context, which isn't the same as my environment.

Is there anyway to achieve automation of networking disconnection remotely and then turning on again the network connection state ? (simulation tools are also ok for me if they do achieve my goal and can be integrated in TFS pipeline or VM tools installation).

Comment: *My goal is to automate test case when there is no network connection inside the VM (mainly no internet connection) to verify that some features of my software under test behave as expected and do not use network to achieve my test calls.* Have you considered implementing this as a unit test? Writing an integration test for this scenario is *extremely* difficult, as you're discovering.

Comment: That seems to be a good idea indeed !, I'll give it a try. Thanks !